# Job keeps failing after issue has been fixed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm really new to using git so this might be a dumb issue, but somehow my colleague also doesn't know how to fix it. 
So i **pushed my code** which worked without a problem. 
When trying to **commit** i kept having an issue where it came out that the **node.js version was too old.** 
My colleague fixed the issue and updated the node.js version. 
However when i try to **"Rerun failed jobs"** it is still giving me the same issue as before. 
I tried to **push the code again and commit again** but it obviously tells me that everything is **already up-to-date.** 
When trying to pull the code again i just get the code that i already pushed.
My next try would be to push the wrong code again just to immediately push the right one afterwards, but i feel like there has to be a better way. Has anyone experienced this before and knows a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The described behavior is how Azure DevOps works.

In order to get a run with your new code you should create a new run using the -> **Run Pipeline** button. This will checkout your new code. When using rerun failed job, the Azure DevOps will keep the same code, settings and will try to rerun the same job. That's why your pipeline fails.

[image]

The same apply with the releases. Every time you need to get a new Release (after you updated your pipeline) you should use the **Create Release** button and not run the previous failed one.

To conclude you should first commit your changes with the updated node version and then run a new pipeline.